# D3D11 Unresolved External Symbol in VC2012

Tags: linker, direct3d, visual-c++

I'm a newbie to D3D dev and when i tried to compiled the d3d11 tutorial example given by microsoft it always failed with unresolved external symbol.

I tried to copy the lib folder to project, and add .lib file dependency in project properties but didn't work

Comment: What is the undefined symbol?

Comment: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ)

Comment: There is an answer to this problem on MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c2cc948f-ee9d-4bc8-b1d4-e0eebd68e5ab/unresolved-external-symbol-vc-2008

Comment: thank you but it doesn't works still since MS remove that tabpage in VS2012, and i've copyed these files in my project already

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear from the description, it seems that you are using the Win32 desktop Direct3D tutorial sample and not the Windows Store app sample. I suggest trying with the latest version of this tutorial from [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef).